# Populate data with custom function

Tags: yadcf

How can I add custom filter options AND all the other data to a custom function?

Below is my code. I would like to have Yes and No filters, but also filters for  all the other values in the column.

```
{column_number: creator_index,
             filter_type: 'custom_func',
             custom_func: Creator_Filter_Function,
              data: [
                      {value: 'yes', label: 'Yes'},
                      {value: 'no', label: 'No'},
                  ],
              filter_default_label: "All"
           },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [append_data_to_table_data](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/a58be6b48d88c7bcba6902f8ffe9663729a66dd0/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L64) option for your filter

From docs:

> - append_data_to_table_data
>               Required:           false
>               Type:               string
>               Default value:      undefined
>               Possible values:    before / sorted
>               Description:        Use 'before' to place your data array before the values that yadcf grabs from the table
>                                   use 'sorted' to place the data array sorted along with the values that yadcf grabs from the table
>               Note:               'sorted' option will have affect only if you data is an array of primitives (not objects)

So eventually your code will look like this

```
{
    append_data_to_table_data: 'before',
    column_number: creator_index,
    filter_type: 'custom_func',
    custom_func: Creator_Filter_Function,
    data: [
        {value: 'yes', label: 'Yes'},
        {value: 'no', label: 'No'},
    ],
    filter_default_label: "All"
},
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the version I am using is old (0.8.7) because I didn't see that in the docs.